# What does it mean to "strafe" the camera?

Tags: camera

I'm looking at a tutorial in which both the terms camera moving and "strafing" are used. I looked onto dictionary.com and found:

> **strafe**
>   verb (used with object)
>   1. to attack (ground troops or installations) by airplanes with
>   machine-gun fire.
>   2. Slang . to reprimand viciously. –noun
>   3. a strafing attack.

WTF???

I'm not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strafing is generally moving directly left or right, instead of rotating the camera.

Answer (score 9):

Strafe is more of a character term than a camera term, although in games I've seen people use it for cameras since they are often directly linked to character movement.

Typically when talking about a camera the movements are.

- Tilt (rotation on fixed position camera to look up/down)
- Pan (rotation on fixed position camera to look left/right)
- Dolly In/Out (physically moving the camera towards or away from the subject)
- Zoom In/Out (changing the focal length of a fixed position camera to make the subject appear larger)
- Truck Left/Right* (physically moving the camera left/right as defined by current orientation, this is what is matched to "Strafe" for characters)
- Pedestal Up/Down (physically move the camera up/down)
- Arc Left/Right (physically orbit the camera around some central object involving a combination of Panning and Trucking)

*Truck is regularly used in TV, but sometimes Dolly is used for both forward/back and left/right movements.

Answer (score 3):

It's a gaming term, so here are the relevant definitions: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafing_%28gaming%29), [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=strafe)

Basically it means translating/moving the camera (or player) left and right, where left and right are defined by the camera's current orientation.